Memory allocations upon declaring a reference
So, when we declare a C++ reference, under the hood a pointer a declared.
The reference in itself doesn't consume any memory, and when we use the address-of operator with a reference, it turns out that reference has the same address as compared to the variable it is referring to.
So, how does it work out, like is it whenever we use the reference the compiler replaces it with the variable it is referring to, or how does that work out?
Also, how can we access the pointer that was declared under the hood when a reference is initialized?
I am really confused and don't know how to think at it.

Using a pointer "under the hood" is one possible implementation, but it's not required. The C++ specification doesn't say anything about it. Think of a reference more like an alias for whatever object you're referencing, not a pointer.

"I am really confused and don't know how to think at it" - Why are you bothered about it ? It is important that you understand the semantics of references, not how they are implemented under the hood (which is not actually specified as mentioned above, and theoretically can be done in a number of ways).

References are not C++ Objects (they don't exist) C++ Object - "...The following entities are not objects: value, reference, function, enumerator, type, non-static class member, template, class or function template specialization, namespace, parameter pack, and this ..."

a reference is an alias. Thinking of a reference as being a pointer is only a good mental model in some cases but not in all and will lead to confusion. A reference is not a pointer.

Also from Reference declaration "...References are not objects; they do not necessarily occupy storage, although the compiler may allocate storage if it is necessary to implement the desired semantics  ..."

"Also how can we access the pointer that was declared under the hood when a reference is initialized?" - You never need to. If you are thinking of reassigning it to reference something else, that has undefined behavior - even if it seems to work in toy programs.

A reference is just an alias, ie a different name for an existing object. There is no "pointer" that you can access (the compiler may use a pointer in certain contexts, but it could just as easily use a CPU register instead, etc). Any use of a reference simply refers to the original object as-if you had specified it directly. That is why taking the address of a reference gives you the address of the object.

"So, how does it work out..." is the right way to think about it. How does it work out. Not: "What goes on under the hood". Because the c++ standard does not specify what is "under the hood". A reference works as if you used the original variable. It only gets more complicated when you expect something to be under the hood that isnt actually there

Sometimes there isn't a "the original variable", such as when you dynamically allocate an object, e.g. int & var = *new int(10);

If you have an object then & gives you the address of that object. But if you have a reference which is implemented as a pointer, then & gives you the value of that pointer. But as already stated, references are not pointers, and it's not always helpful to think of them like that. Just think about how they work, not how they are implemented.

The reference in itself doesn't consume any memory. What do you mean? If you're referring that there is no explicit buffer allocation (such as new or c/m-alloc), that's a different issue. It's not like you can have a reference that reads 100 MB of data and saves it in a variable and it "doesn't consume any memory".

If you want to know how a reference (which is an entity that has lifetime characteristics) make a struct that contains a reference. Create an instance of the struct while initializing the reference.  Then examine the bytes in the struct. In every compiler I've seen, it's a pointer to object it's initialized to.

This question is similar to: C and C++ pass by pointer and pass by reference confusion. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I’m calling this a dup of C and C++ pass by pointer and pass by reference confusion


So, when we declare a C++ reference, under the hood a pointer a declared.

As the commenters have pointed out, this is not necessarily the case. The reference could be implemented as a pointer (e.g. this is likely how std::tuple<int&,int&> would be stored if you stored it, rather than the hopefully optimized out intermediate with std::tie(a,b) = x,y). The compiler is just required to do something that properly handles the standard's specifications for how references behave (and a pointer often does that).

whenever we use the reference the compiler replaces it with the variable it is referring to, or how does that work out?

This is another possibility, depending on how the reference is used. If I am in a loop, and I declare int& val = arr[i], the compiler may never add an actual pointer for it. It just uses the integer at arr[i] when it needs it.

Also, how can we access the pointer that was declared under the hood when a reference is initialized?

If you know that there is such a pointer, you probably can access it by accessing the raw bytes, though it's probably very easy to get undefined behavior this way.
auto refs = std::tie(x,y);
auto bytes = (char*)(&refs);
for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(refs); i+=sizeof(int*))
    std::cout << *(int**)(bytes+i) << std::endl;
std::cout << "==" << std::endl;
std::cout << &x << std::endl;
std::cout << &y << std::endl;


I can’t upvote this because it assumes that the symbol itself will give you access to a valid pointer value. That is straight-up UB.
